# double coin toss(one biased) with distribuitons

Tags: python, statistics, scipy.stats

Is it possible to simulate 10 repetitions of 2 coin flips (one fair, one with 30% chance of getting tails), with a sample of 100 and making a representation of the distribution of the random variables "head head" ,"head tails" ,"tails head" and "tails tails" making use of scipy distributions?

Comment: What kind of representation are you looking for? A histogram?

Comment: Yes. histogram with the 4 possible outcomes

Answer (score 0):

This gives you four individual plots for the chance you set yourself:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

chance = 0.5
for combi in ["TAILS TAILS", "TAILS COINS", "COINS TAILS", "COINS COINS"]:    
    count = []
    for i in range(10):
        draw = ["TAILS" if random.random() > chance else "COINS" for i in range(100)]  
        adjecent = [" ".join([i,j]) for i,j in zip(draw, draw[1:])]
        count.append(adjecent.count(combi))
    plt.figure()
    plt.hist(count)
    plt.title(combi + f" with chance {chance}")
    plt.show()
```

You could put this in another loop to do it for both fair (`chance = 0.5`) and biased (`chance = 0.7`) to create 8 histograms. Or you could [loop through a subplot grid](https://engineeringfordatascience.com/posts/matplotlib_subplots/). Hope this helps.